# Unable to kill Running Queries in Spark UI and Write to sql server never happens

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

I have a simple code which will read entire Hive table and load it to SQL Server in Azure Databricks.

```
    df = spark.sql("select * from Mechanics")
    df.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")\
.mode("overwrite").option("url",sql_connection_properties)\
.option("dbtable",glb.mechanics_invoices)\
.option("user",username).option("password",pwd)\
.option("bulkCopyBatchSize",10000).save()
```

On executing this cell, the command keeps on running for minutes. I am unable to kill. Because in SparkUI neither Job or Stage gets created. I can only see Running Queries(1). No option to kill.

> If I try the same for another table or glb.mechanics_invoices_temp it
> runs successfully.

Tried to check locks in SQL Server but I dont have privileges to check.

What is the mistake I am doing here?
Hive table contains 2700490 rows.

1. How to kill such processes either by pyspark code or from UI
2. Any suggestions to above code Performant,Fail safe especially by using the options like bulkCopyTableLock, bulkCopyTimeout, partitions etc.
3. Any resources to understand above situation better.

Appreciate your feedback and suggestions.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> How to kill such processes either by pyspark code or from UI

you can kill the Spark application from the **Web UI**, by accessing the application master page of spark job.

- Opening Spark cluster UI- master.
- Expand Running Application.
- Find a job you wanted to kill.
- Select `kill` to stop the Job.

[image]

Comment: I checked the Running Queries section, but the kill option is not available in this scenario. I suspect that the table in sql server which I am writing to is getting locked and hence the queries are taking indefinite time. The process itself is not starting.